# How to call a function when all elements (called by ajax) have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call a function when all the elements in the div called by ajax are loaded.
Jquery:

```
$('#load-div').load('ex-page.php');
$('#load-div').ready(function(){
     alert('loaded');   
});
```

I also tried other ways like: load (), on('load'), $elems = $('#main').find('img'),... But it does not work or not exactly (
The function is called when the main document has been loaded, when img or background of some div is loading,...).

Answer (score 2):

See https://api.jquery.com/load/

You can pass a second parameter to `load()` which is a function being called when the resource has been loaded :

```
$('#load-div').load('ex-page.php', function(){
  alert('loaded');   
});
```

**Edited for below comment :**

```
$(function() { // when document is ready
  $('#load-div').load('ex-page.php', function(){ // do the ajax call and alert when it's loaded
      alert('loaded');   
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it but the function was called when the document was half loaded,i  think it was called when the first element was loaded

Comment: I've added another way to do what you want.
This will wait for the document to be loaded, then do the ajax request, and alert when this is loaded.

You can also do something with variables with both element loading synchronously.

Comment: I tried this way but again the function is called when the first element in ex-page is loaded.

Comment: @Mido does your ex-page.php bring some javascript and ajax calls too ?

Comment: No, it only has some img and div tags with a background image. I tried in specific id of img tag and it worked. But not with document or parent element.